# Filter Contact with prefix number

Tags: android, contacts, prefix

I have function to load all contact number in android, and now i want to filter all contact number with prefix "0878","0877","0817" so contact number with that prefix will be loaded, and here my current code :

```
private void loadContact(){
    ContentResolver cr = applicationContext.getContentResolver();
    String [] PROJECTION = ContactsQuery.PROJECTION;

    Cursor cursor = cr.query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            PROJECTION,
            null,
            null,
            null
    );

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        //String name = cursor.getString(ContactsQuery.DISPLAY_NAME);
        String lookUpKey = cursor.getString(ContactsQuery.LOOKUP_KEY);
        loadContactDetail(lookUpKey);
    }
    cursor.close();
}

private void loadContactDetail(String lookUpKey){
    ContentResolver cr = applicationContext.getContentResolver();

    String [] COLS = {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};

    Cursor cursor = cr.query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, COLS,
            ContactsContract.Data.LOOKUP_KEY + " = ?",
            new String[]{lookUpKey},
            null
    );

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String phone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        String formatted = Util.formatMSISDN(phone);
        if(formatted != null)
            contactsSet.add(formatted);
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String phone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        String formatted = Util.formatMSISDN(phone);
        if(formatted != null){
            if(formatted.startsWith("0878") || formatted.startsWith("0877") || formatted.startsWith("0817"))
               contactsSet.add(formatted);
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
```

Comment: i want to use all that prefix so better use || or && ?

Comment: you have to use all the prefix so you have to use ||

Comment: is your contacts really starts with 0878? or before that it has any + symbols or spaces?

Comment: There is some number with + and 08 that code should filter contact with 08 right? But when i try there is no contact filtered..

Comment: You have to remove the number with + and apply filter or filter with the + and numbers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162778/discussion-between-asqa-and-sky-alligator).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the sourceString.contains(CharSequence) method.

Comment: confused with your answer :)

Comment: String sourceString = "0878956985";
if (sourceString.contains("0878")) {
 // 0878 do exist inside your source string
} else {
 // 0878 not exists inside your source string
}